# Laravel with in with

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm

I need to count people with status X where more than one items.

Models: People, Items, Status

```
People->items() = belongstomany with item_people table as intermediate    
 
Items->statuses() = belongstomany with item_statuses table as intermediate
```

```
People::with(['items','items.statuses' => function ($q){
            $q->whereIn('item_statuses.title', ['X'])
        })
        ->whereHas('items.statuses',function ($q){
            $q->whereIn('statuses.title', ['X'])
        ->withCount('items')->having('items_count','>',1)->get()->count();
```

But It does count (it shouldn't) items without status 'X' - due to eadger load `with items`, which I can't filter out using with.

I tried this, but It doesn't work because it searches for column only inside statuses:

```
..::with(['items.statuses' => function ($q){
            $q->whereIn('items.item_statuses.title', ['X'])
        })...
```

I can do it via loop later after getting query but can I do this like that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to constraint your withCount as well :

```
People::with(['items','items.statuses' => function ($q){
            $q->whereIn('item_statuses.title', ['X'])
        })
        ->whereHas('items.statuses',function ($q){
            $q->whereIn('statuses.title', ['X'])
        ->withCount(['items' => function($q){
$q->whereHas('statuses', function($q){
 $q->whereIn('item_statuses.title', ['X'])
});
}])->having('items_count','>',1)->get()->count();
```

Now if I understand what you want to do :

I need to count people with status X where more than one items.

Then you should do this :

```
People::whereHas('items', function($query){
            $query->whereHas('statuses', function($query){
                $query->whereIn('item_statuses.title', ['X']);
            });
        }, '>', 1)->count();
```